# No trailing slash - Angular $stateprovider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My routes for a Angular 1 application is as below

```
$stateProvider
  .state('loginHome',
  {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "scripts/spa/features/account/views/login.html"
  })
  .state('login',
  {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "scripts/spa/features/account/views/login.html"
  });
```

In production, a user can use the URL - http://myserver/mywebapp with no trailing slash. What route can I add to ensure that the user gets redirected to login when there's no slash in the end? Currently, the angular fails to load the login view when there's no slash.

PS: There maybe a IIS option to force a trailing slash but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: why do you need a trailing slash? Sounds like an XY problem

Comment: what does the app load instead of the login view?

Comment: @Claies It doesn't load the login view. I have angular boostrapped from the Index.cshtml in a MVC project. It just loads the Index.cshtml file

Comment: @charlietfl Not sure I understand. I need the users to be able to use the website when they don't use the "/"

Comment: so what is inside the `index.cshtml`? is that your angular app? does it have an `ng-view` in it? what content appears inside the `ng-view` (if it exists)?

Comment: I don't understand why there would be a trailing slash in the first place... angular router doesn't expect it. Perhaps IIS forces one...I don't do much IIS work and most other servers don't add one by default. Note: am also assuming you are using `html5mode` in router

Comment: Am  also assuming you have set up `web.config` to always point to angular app entry point

Comment: @charlietfl I don't believe I've setup the web.config to point to the entry point. What key/element needs to be setup for that?

Comment: are you using html5mode in your router? If not you shouldn't need to do anything server side, otherwise I am not very IIS proficient and it should be an easy search